# removeFromSupper crashed

Tags: ios, crash

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.XM.CSee>:63401 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Background
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-update
WatchdogVisibility: Background
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 33.600 (user 33.600, system 0.000), 52% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 13.351, 21% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreAutoLayout                         0x199482d2c NSBitSetCount + 28
1   CoreAutoLayout                         0x199486064 _table_removeStorageBlockIfPossible + 59
2   CoreAutoLayout                         0x19948307c _engineVar_rawRemove + 191
3   CoreAutoLayout                         0x199482220 -[NSISEngine removeConstraintWithMarker:] + 659
4   CoreAutoLayout                         0x19948ae64 -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:] + 207
5   UIKitCore                              0x183edb1f0 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 199
6   CoreAutoLayout                         0x19947fbac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 79
7   UIKitCore                              0x1840b82bc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 187
8   UIKitCore                              0x183eebed8 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 95
9   CoreAutoLayout                         0x19947fbac -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 79
10  UIKitCore                              0x183f77af8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 779
11  UIKitCore                              0x183ead7dc __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 163
12  UIKitCore                              0x183ebea70 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 395
13  iCSee                                  0x1030d06a4 -[RightToolView configToolViewSupportFull:supportRatio:supportSplit:supportLight:supportPIP:supportManualAlert:] + 147 (RightToolView.m:38)
14  iCSee                                  0x10274e168 -[XMCameraViewController configToolBarRight:] + 635 (XMCameraViewController.mm:1378)
15  iCSee                                  0x1027f4ef0 -[XMCameraViewController mediaPlayer:info1:info2:] + 2323 (XMCameraViewController.mm:9896)
16  iCSee                                  0x103263334 -[MediaPlayerModel OnFunSDKResult:] + 7075 (MediaPlayerModel.mm:408)
17  iCSee                                  0x10304ec08 -[RealPlayModel OnFunSDKResult:] + 79 (RealPlayModel.mm:113)
18  Foundation                             0x18319d58c -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 875
19  Foundation                             0x18313d1e8 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 131
20  iCSee                                  0x103c12a7c invocation function for block in UI_SendMsg(int, XMSG*) + 287 (UIInterface.mm:134)
21  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18173f094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
22  libdispatch.dylib                      0x181740094 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
23  libdispatch.dylib                      0x181721858 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 887
24  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1817214d0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 35
25  CoreFoundation                         0x181a3aab4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 11
26  CoreFoundation                         0x1819f7fd8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2543
27  CoreFoundation                         0x181a0ac30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 571
28  GraphicsServices                       0x1a2431988 GSEventRunModal + 159
29  UIKitCore                              0x184205c50 -[UIApplication _run] + 1079
30  UIKitCore                              0x183f9f3d0 UIApplicationMain + 335
31  iCSee                                  0x1032675b8 main + 115 (main.m:17)
32  dyld                                   0x10733c3d0 start + 443
```

The crash occurred when I exited the app interface with the specific crash stack on top
How do I stop this random crash
The crash occurred when I exited the app interface with the specific crash stack on top
How do I stop this random crash
The crash occurred when I exited the app interface with the specific crash stack on top
How do I stop this random crash

Comment: Hi. Maybe you can try to catch it on breakpoint. Or show a snippet of the code